# Notepad++ show results of search in one row even when occurs several times in text

Tags: search, text, format, find, notepad++

I have some Testlog-files and want to check them with notepad ++. E.g. I am looking for the Word ERROR while using "Find all in current document" This gives me a row for each occurrence. But I want only one row per Test of my Testlog-file:

My Testlog-file looks somewhat like that:

```
Test 111,  Name: ABC, ERROR 3, ERROR 5, ERROR 7, 1.1.22,
Test 222,  Name: xyz, ERROR 26, 1.1.22,
Test 333,  Name: xyz, 1.1.22,
Test 444,  Name: mno, ERROR 32, ERROR 15,  1.1.22,
Test 555,  Name: qwe, 1.1.22,
Test 666,  Name: rtz, 1.1.22,
```

The result when searching for **ERROR -find all in Document** I get is:

```
Test 111,  Name: ABC, ERROR 3, ERROR 5, ERROR 7, 1.1.22,
Test 111,  Name: ABC, ERROR 3, ERROR 5, ERROR 7, 1.1.22,
Test 111,  Name: ABC, ERROR 3, ERROR 5, ERROR 7, 1.1.22,
Test 222,  Name: xyz, ERROR 26, 1.1.22,
Test 444,  Name: mno, ERROR 32, ERROR 15,  1.1.22,
Test 444,  Name: mno, ERROR 32, ERROR 15,  1.1.22,
```

but I want

```
Test 111,  Name: ABC, ERROR 3, ERROR 5, ERROR 7, 1.1.22,
Test 222,  Name: xyz, ERROR 26, 1.1.22,
Test 444,  Name: mno, ERROR 32, ERROR 15,  1.1.22,
```

**How can I get only 1 line for each no matter how many Errors I got?** There is another post about removing duplicate rows but this does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:.*?ERROR)+`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    .*?         # 0 or more any character but newline
    ERROR       # the word to be searched
)+          # end group, must appear 1 or more times
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]